# Generate a .csv with java and download in local

Tags: javascript, java

I generate a .csv file in my class but I want this look like how when  a  user download the file  with browser. Currently the program download file in background scene and I need looks like a normal download, help?

```
String archCSV = "C:\\"+nombre;
File file = new File(archCSV);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( fw );       

while (rs.next())
{
    befichero = new BEContenidofichero();
    befichero.setsContenido(rs.getString("Contenido"));

    writer.write(befichero.getsContenido());
    writer.write("\n");
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: What does *this question* have to do with javascript?

Comment: I do in java and javascript is a jsp project and i show the part of code when I generate the file...

Comment: I call this java with ajax function

Answer (score 0):

I use a servlet for generate a CSV file.